# Drawing a rounded cornered NSTextFieldCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfieldcell

My code for my NSTextFieldCell is:

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
    // Drawing code here.
    NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor] endingColor:[NSColor grayColor]];
    [gradient drawInRect:cellFrame angle:90];
    [[self title] drawInRect:cellFrame withAttributes:nil];

}
```

I would like to have the NSTextFieldCell to have rounded corners.... how could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the layer property of NSView, then you can set a corner radius for this.

Comment: How would I set the corner radius?

Comment: controlView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5;